# Google-sheets sumifs

Tags: google-sheets

Counting income and outgoings in 2 month periods, Works perfectly March to November, but not after this?

Formulas on the GST Summary tab
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10KffbQ29vr8c7gz2bep3kX0-U92SAxM81rzUB9kdzbs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). The sample spreadsheet gives "Access denied." See [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: Not being able to see your sheet, I'm guessing that the cross-over between December and January (i.e., between one year and another) may be the problem, if you didn't account for this at the outset. But as doubleunary points out, your sheet is currently inaccessible. So that guess is all I can offer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't include the information needed to answer.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your input. I changed the sumifs, to sum with a filter, and that's fixed the across years error.
Really appreciate your comments.
Cheers